# Renaming database, what am I doing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm attempting to rename a database in SQL Server 2008.

I've done this a number of ways, using the object explorer, script, physically renaming the file, and detaching the database and attaching it back as the database with the name I want.

I want to rename my database to `Counter`, so when I say

```
Use Counter
GO
```

this runs fine.

However from my program that accesses the database instead of seeing the `Counter` database and using it, it's seeing the old name of `Counter` (`counter_a`) and throwing an error. Is there anyway to stop this from happening and totally eradicate this old name?

I changed the file name for the database and log (which was the old name) after I attached it  using

```
USE Counter 

ALTER DATABASE Counter 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'Counter_a', NEWNAME = N'Counter')

ALTER DATABASE Dpac 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'Counter_a_log', NEWNAME = N'Counter_log')
```

Now the physical names are correct.

However in my connection string, if I rename the database to `counter_a` in

```
<DatabasePath value="Data Source=127.0.0.1;initial catalog=counter_a;Integrated Security = TRUE" />
```

AND I rename my database in SQL Server to `counter_a` program works fine.

HOWEVER. If I use

```
<DatabasePath value="Data Source=127.0.0.1;initial catalog=counter;Integrated Security = TRUE" />
```

in config and I rename the SAME database from `counter_a` to `counter` I can't connect.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What program is accessing the database? Can you set the database? A lot of programs cache the database structure because it is slow to get. You might need to empty cache.

Comment: Fix your application/program code to point to correct database?

Comment: So how does your app know which db to connect to?

Comment: Try stop and start SQL

Comment: @rs. the program pointing does not have to change since another database was Renamed to the database the program points too

Comment: @DamienBlack Database name is in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user you are connecting with has a default database of the old database name. You can change the default database in SSMS, just set it to the new database name, or master.

The other possibility is there is a reference to the old name in the connection string of the application, or within the application itself.

Comment: The Default database for the user is Counter, Also in the config file. 
  <DatabasePath value="Data Source=127.0.0.1;initial catalog=Counter;Integrated Security = TRUE" />
So it is not referencing the old name in the connection string